# .Net Framework problem

Tags: vb.net

While trying to install my application, when system tries to install .Net Framework, it gives an error. 
Is there any source where I could download uninstalled .Net Framework 3.0 and provide my clients with application?

Thanks and best regards,
Furqan

Comment: Can you please tell us more about error?

Comment: I have a screenshot of the error.  Can I send you an email?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot Net Framework 3.0 Redistributable

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=10cc340b-f857-4a14-83f5-25634c3bf043&displaylang=en

Or the latest in 3.x (3.5 SP1)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

Or the latest Redistributable 
Dot Net Framework 4
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7